# Spring boot retuns only culry braces

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, spring-data

Entity

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "tbl_book")
@Data
@Getter
@Setter
@ToString
public class Book {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private long id;

    @Column(name="sku")
    private String sku;

    @Column(name="name")
    private String name;

    @Column(name="description")
    private String description;

    @Column(name="unit_price")
    private BigDecimal unitPrice;

    @Column(name="image_url")
    private String imageUrl;

    @Column(name="active")
    private boolean active;

    @Column(name="units_in_stock")
    private int unitsInStock;

    @Column(name="date_created")
    private Date createdOn;

    @Column(name="last_updated")
    private Date updatedOn;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name="category_id",nullable=false)
    private BookCategory category;

}
```

Controllar

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping(path="/api/v1")
public class BookController {

@Autowired
    public BookService bookService;

@GetMapping("/books")
    public ResponseEntity<List<Book>> getAllBooks() {
        return new ResponseEntity<>(bookService.getAllBooks(),HttpStatus.OK);
    }
}
```

Service

```
@Service
public class BookService {

    @Autowired
    public BookRepository bookRepository;

    public List<Book> getAllBooks(){
        List<Book> books = bookRepository.findAll();
        System.out.println("books:"+books);
        return books;
    }

}
```

[Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NOeTA.png)

LOG

Hibernate: select book0_.id as id1_0_, book0_.active as active2_0_, book0_.category_id as categor11_0_, book0_.date_created as date_cre3_0_, book0_.description as descript4_0_, book0_.image_url as image_ur5_0_, book0_.name as name6_0_, book0_.sku as sku7_0_, book0_.unit_price as unit_pri8_0_, book0_.units_in_stock as units_in9_0_, book0_.last_updated as last_up10_0_ from tbl_book book0_
Hibernate: select bookcatego0_.id as id1_1_0_, bookcatego0_.category_name as category2_1_0_ from tbl_category bookcatego0_ where bookcatego0_.id=?
books:[in.kunjyadav.onlinebookstore.model.Book@3c5934ee, in.kunjyadav.onlinebookstore.model.Book@49280d55, in.kunjyadav.onlinebookstore.model.Book@dbe2143, in.kunjyadav.onlinebookstore.model.Book@63997579, in.kunjyadav.onlinebookstore.model.Book@1692c3a0, in.kunjyadav.onlinebookstore.model.Book@1f593682, in.kunjyadav.onlinebookstore.model.Book@6391b813, in.kunjyadav.onlinebookstore.model.Book@4b0b3ba5, in.kunjyadav.onlinebookstore.model.Book@4b846ea7, in.kunjyadav.onlinebookstore.model.Book@1dbfbc73]

Please help...

Comment: add book entity, please

Comment: @Komdosh Please check now...

Comment: you don't need to annotate entity with Data + Getter\Setter\ToString, because this is already included in Data. That's problem usually apear when you don't have public getters, but you already have it. Do you have another errors in your log?

Comment: but I have removed @Data now but not any changes there output and logs...

Comment: Do you have a BookRepositoryImpl class.?

Answer (score 0):

Provide this `@EnableJpaRepositories(basePackages = "your.package")` to your config class.